# How to aggregate continuous data into daily data with R

Tags: r, facebook, aggregation, xts

I extracted data from facebook's API with the help of rfacebook. I ran a sentiment analysis using a support vector machine classifying each message as either positive or negative.

The data I have now looks like

```
fromID    fromName     Message     createdTime                 SVM Label

122233    Max Muster   great game  2014-12-28T20:57:04+0000            1
133425    Hilde Mash   hate it!    2014-12-28T23:54:12+0000            2
142233    Fred Ast     awesome     2014-12-29T22:37:08+0000            1
139425    Fred Fein    hate it!    2014-12-28T12:21:06+0000            2
```

I first transformed the createdTime column into xts format by applying

`df$createdTime = strptime(df$createdTime,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`

Then I first try to aggregate the number of comments per day with

```
number = apply.daily(df, sum)
```

However, this seems to be not working.

number only consists of NA.

I tried several other stuff, but it is not working.

At best I would love to have a data frame which counts how many 1 and 2 SVM Labels I have per day. However, I am not sure how to do this.

Any help here would be really appreciated!

Best thanks beforehand for your kind help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the xts package at all, so I have instead used POSIXct format.

Assuming your data frame is called "df":

```
df$Time = as.POSIXct(df$createdTime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")  
library(dplyr)  
df2 = df %>%   
  mutate(Day = as.POSIXct(trunc.POSIXt(Time, units = "days"))) %>%  
  group_by(Day, SVMLabel) %>%  
  summarise(Count = n())  

print(df2)
```

For the data above, this gives me:

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: Day [?]

```
     Day       SVMLabel Count
  (time)          (int) (int)
1 2014-12-28        1     1
2 2014-12-28        2     2
3 2014-12-29        1     1
```

Which looks right to me.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was also very helpful and works as well very good!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$createdTime)
summary_df <- df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(class1 = sum(SVMLabel == 1), class2 = sum(SVMLabel == 2))
```

Alternatively, you can also use the table command and convert to data frame as follows:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$createdTime)
summary_df <- as.data.frame(table(df$Date, df$SVMLabel))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me alot!